# SQL Script to determine publish volume

Tags: publishing

As the title states, does any body have some findings on determining the publishing volume (the amount of Entries to be published)?

Basically, what I'd love to find is if there is a script that counts the amount of items to be published by each publishing method: Incremental (*this one is relatively easy, as we have the PublishQueue*), Smart and Republish.

For the last two, would it be enough just to count **all items in all versions in all languages**?

Comment: `web` database contains only the latest (approved) version in every language. So full Republish would publish max 1 version  per every language of an item. But if item is in a workflow and not in the final step, it won't be published. Or if some publish restrictions are set, it might not be published. Or if one of the ancestors cannot be published for any reason, well it depends on the configuration... No, there is no easy way to get the information you need using sql query.

Comment: Have you inspected the Sitecore Publishing Service? If I recall they have ways of assessing in batch how many items will be published.

Comment: @MichaelWest that's a good point, but unfortunately we are using normal publishing

Comment: Then perhaps you can determine how the publishing service is doing that and duplicate it through script.

Comment: @MarekMusielak that is why I asked this question. Maybe someone has already gone through this and has some snippets in place. I am pretty sure that I am not the first one who need something like this